# Detect in node.js whether system bluetooth device is disconnected

Tags: node.js, macos, bluetooth

I'm using node.js (with Electron) as a middleware on OS X interfacing with two Bluetooth devices. Every now and the Bluetooth device (driver) crashes. I'm not able to enable/disable it anymore and it doesn't respond.

Only reloading the Bluetooth driver works (via `kextunload`and `kextload`).

So is there a way/module to detect whether a device has been disconnected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be using socketio, no? It's a guess; and if not, please show what you are using to allow others to help.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
  console.log('disconnect!');
});
```